# Fetch text around the parentheses from a pandas dataframe column and copy the output to the same column

Tags: python, regex

I want to fetch only the text around parenthesis and keep this text in the same column.

I have the following dataframe df:

```
id     feature
1      mutation(MI:0118)
2      mutation(MI:0119)
3      mutation(MI:01120)
```

The expected output is:

```
id     feature
1      MI:0118
2      MI:0119
3      MI:01120
```

I tried the following regex but it is not allowing me to copy it to the same column.

```
df['feature'] = df['feature'].str.extract(r"\((.*?)\)", expand=False)
```

I am getting following warning and the above code is converting all the values in the feature column to NaN

```
/home/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
```

Thanks

Comment: Well, `df['feature'] = df['feature'].str.extract(r"\((.*?)\)", expand=False)` works on my end. If it fails for you, try `df['feature'] = df['feature'].str.replace(r".*\(([^()]*)\).*', r'\1')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the below code with a different pattern:

```
df['feature'] = df['feature'].str.extract('.*\((.*)\).*', expand=False)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   id   feature
0   1   MI:0118
1   2   MI:0119
2   3  MI:01120
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ANq7Cm/1)

Comment: Yes, it is working fine. Could you please explain this '.*\((.*)\).*' regex? Thanks

Comment: @ranusharma check here: https://regex101.com/r/ANq7Cm/1 and the top right corner is the explanation, please accept my answer and upvote it too.

Comment: @U10-Forward Sorry for being quick before. But after trying your code too, I am getting the copy error. :(

Comment: @ranusharma Try adding `import warnings;warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")` to the top of the file

Comment: @ranusharma It isn't caused by this, ask another question if you want, and accept my answer too :P